# I can't add success message on the popup frontend

Tags: magento2, jquery, popup

I am trying to use:

```
Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList

messageList.addSuccessMessage({ message: 'You have subscribed Successfully' });
```

But its not working . I tried adding success message in the **controller** but its not showing up as well .

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
        'mage/cookies',

        ], function ($, modal,messageList) {
        'use strict';
        debugger;
         if(!$.cookie('popup_cookie') ) {
             $.widget('devall.popupManager', {

                /**
                 *
                 * @private
                 */

                _create: function () {

                    var self = this,
                        popup_devnewsletter_options = {
                            type: 'popup',
                            responsive: true,
                            innerScroll: true,
                            title: this.options.popupTitle,
                            buttons: false,
                            modalClass: 'popup-devnewsletter'
                        };
                    var expDate = new Date();

                    expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (3650000 * 60 * 1000));
                    $.cookie('popup_cookie', 1, {expires: expDate});

                    modal(popup_devnewsletter_options, this.element);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        self._setStyleCss();
                        self.element.modal('openModal');
                    }, 3000);
                    this.element.find('form').submit(function () {
                        if ($(this).validation('isValid')) {
                            console.log("Hello 1!");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                                cache: true,
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                showLoader: true,
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                console.log("Hello 2!");
                                self.element.find('.popup-manager .messages').html(data.message);
                                if (data.error) {
                                    self.element.find('.messages .message').addClass('message-error error');
                                    self.element.find('.messages .message').addClass('message-success success');
                                    messageList.addSuccessMessage({ message: 'You have subscribed Successfully' });
                                    self.element.modal('closeModal');
                                    // var cookieExpires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.options.cookieLifetime * 1000);

                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        self.element.modal('closeModal');
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                                self.element.find('.messages').show();
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    self.element.find('.messages').hide();
                                }, 5000);
                            }) 

                        }
                        return false;
                    });


                    this._resetStyleCss();
                },

                /**
                 * Set width of the popup
                 * @private
                 */
                _setStyleCss: function (width) {

                    width = width || 400;

                    if (window.innerWidth > 786) {
                        this.element.parent().parent('.modal-inner-wrap').css({'max-width': width + 'px'});
                    }
                },

                /**
                 * Reset width of the popup
                 * @private
                 */
                _resetStyleCss: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        if (window.innerWidth <= 786) {
                            self.element.parent().parent('.modal-inner-wrap').css({'max-width': 'initial'});
                        } else {
                            self._setStyleCss(self.options.innerWidth);
                        }
                    });
                },

            });

            return $.devall.popupManager;
        }

        return 0; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `customer-data` to display message.

> Magento_Customer/js/customer-data,

```
customerData.set('messages', {
    messages: [{
        type: 'success',
        text: 'Your message'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Its not working